# aws application load balancer not accessible from the internet? timesout but no requests show up under 'monitor'

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-vpc

I'm using terraform to build an application load balancer that forwards requests to targate group that has a fargate service attached to it.

However, the requests don't seem to be getting to the load balancer at all.

I can try to access the DNS url showing up but it will timeout with `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` on chrome, not the 'GATEWAY TIMEOUT' bit.

Monitor charts remain completely flat with nothing detected.

- application load balancer:

```
resource "aws_lb" "main" {
  name                       = "main"
  internal                   = false
  load_balancer_type         = "application"
  security_groups            = [aws_security_group.public.id]
  enable_deletion_protection = false
  subnets                    = [aws_subnet.public.id, aws_subnet.public-backup.id]
}
```

- VPC

```
resource "aws_vpc" "main" {
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/18"

  tags = {
    Name = "Main VPC"
  }
}
```

- subnet

```
resource "aws_subnet" "public" {
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.main.id
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/27"

  availability_zone = "eu-west-2a"

  tags = {
    Name = "Public Subnet"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "public-backup" {
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.main.id
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.32/27"

  availability_zone = "eu-west-2b"

  tags = {
    Name = "Public Backup Subnet"
  }
}
```

- vpc gateway

```
resource "aws_internet_gateway" "main" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.main.id
}
```

- security group and rule

```
resource "aws_security_group" "public" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.main.id
  name   = "public"

  tags = {
    name = "Public Security Group"
  }
}

### outbound rules
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "public_out" {
  type        = "egress"
  from_port   = 0
  to_port     = 0
  protocol    = "-1"
  cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]

  security_group_id = aws_security_group.public.id
}

### inbound rules
# ssh
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "public_in_ssh" {
  type        = "ingress"
  from_port   = 22
  to_port     = 22
  protocol    = "tcp"
  cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]

  security_group_id = aws_security_group.public.id
}
# http
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "public_in_http" {
  type        = "ingress"
  from_port   = 80
  to_port     = 80
  protocol    = "tcp"
  cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]

  security_group_id = aws_security_group.public.id
}
# https
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "public_in_https" {
  type        = "ingress"
  from_port   = 443
  to_port     = 443
  protocol    = "tcp"
  cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]

  security_group_id = aws_security_group.public.id
}
```

- lb listeners for port 80 and 443

```
resource "aws_lb_listener" "websocket-server" {
  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.main.arn
  port              = "443"
  protocol          = "HTTPS"
  ssl_policy        = "ELBSecurityPolicy-2016-08"
  certificate_arn   = aws_acm_certificate.main.arn


  default_action {
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.websocket-server.arn
    type             = "forward"
  }
}

resource "aws_lb_listener" "http" {
  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.main.arn
  port              = "80"
  protocol          = "HTTP"

  default_action {
    type = "redirect"

    redirect {
      port        = "443"
      protocol    = "HTTPS"
      status_code = "HTTP_301"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a security group allowing traffic from the ALB to the actual containers?

Comment: For now, I've attached the same public security group described above to the ECS service as well, but the main issue isn't the load balancer getting to the actual container, but internet traffic getting to the LB at all

I have temporarily attached the private security group to that as well but that didn't help, I'm guessing that might be an issue later down the line once I can access the LB itself

Comment: Is the service also listening on port 443?

Comment: @MarkoE yes -- the docker container port is 443,  and the same 443 port is configured everywhere relevant (task/service/tg/listener)

Comment: Ok and are you assigning a public IP to the ECS service?

Comment: yes although in this other stackoverflow thread someone was suggesting strongly that this is something I want to avoid due to wanting the load balancer to provide the public access to the ECS and not have the ECS directly accessible from the internet

Comment: I would have to agree with them. Additionally, you can put the containers in a private subnet and ALB will still be able to communicate with them.

Comment: @MarkoE I was missing several pieces of infrastructure such a routing tables/routing roles, nat gateway, eip on the nat gateway. Since adding those, I can access it and hit the `503 Service Temporarily Unavailable` so now I'm back to helping the load balancer access the actual fargate service.

Comment: If you're getting `503 unavailable` now, you should be focusing on the health checks in the target group, and the access logs of your ECS service, not the load balancer access logs.